# How to avoid `RuntimeWarning` for divide by zero when the value is unusued?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to write a function to calculate the `(exp(x) - 1) / x`, taking into the account the fact that as `x` approaches `0` the function approaches `1`.   I have the following implementation

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(x == 0, 1.0, np.expm1(x) / x)
```

This is correct in the sense that it returns correct values, but the annoying thing is that when it is called with an `x` argument that contains zeros, it issues a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide`.  I understand that this is because the division by zero actually happens in the third argument of `where` although those `nan` values are never used.

Is there a better implementation or a way to avoid the annoying warning?

Comment: Just ignore the warning? You can silence warnings globally or using a context manage (a `with`)

Comment: How is this ever going to divide by `0`, if you've set the condition to be `x == 0`?

Comment: @yatu because it still evaluates `np.expm1(x) / x`

Comment: Use a try-except clause. You should handle the cases where divide by 0 occurs as they can be quite costly. I would not recommend suppressing warnings as it may cause issues if a real issue happens elsewhere.

Comment: @JasonChia there is no exception to handle here. In any case, you can silence the warnings for just that expression.

Comment: Hmm true, `np.where` does evaluate the whole thing @juanpa

Comment: @yatu `numpy.where` never gets a chance to do anything else, that is evaluated before it is even passed to `numpy.where`.

Comment: Oooh. Perhaps just a case to check for 0?

Comment: I'd suggest something like this `np.divide(np.expm1(x), x, out=np.ones_like(x), where=b!=0)`

Comment: So if x == 0: sub np.expm1(x)/x with Nan

Comment: Yes gotcha @juanpa , kind of forgot how `np.where` works there

Comment: @yatu not to belabor the point, *but it has nothing to do with `numpy.where*, it's a fundamental aspect of how Python works. The only reason I'm trying to be clear is there are some languages where an expression isn't necessarily evaluated when it is passed as an argument.

Comment: @juanpa yes, it makes sense since there's nothing being evaluated here for each value. The whole condition is evaluated in a vectorized manner and the resulting ndarray is filled according to the condition.